# Rounding with javascript and coldfusion

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I am working with someone else's code that works.
I just need it to round to the scond decimal place. What it does is when you enter in numbers it adds it or subtracts it to another field on the page

```
<cfset TextJS = TextJS & "var $EH_LEFH#CurrentRow# = $('##EH_LEFH#CurrentRow#');var $MH_LEFH#CurrentRow# = $('##MH_LEFH#CurrentRow#');$EH_LEFH#CurrentRow#.keyup(function () {$MH_LEFH#CurrentRow#.val(parseFloat($(this).val()) - #getLast.LTSN#);});">
<cfset TextJS = TextJS & "var $EH_LCYCLES#CurrentRow# = $('##EH_LCYCLES#CurrentRow#');var $MH_LCYCLES#CurrentRow# = $('##MH_LCYCLES#CurrentRow#');$EH_LCYCLES#CurrentRow#.keyup(function () {$MH_LCYCLES#CurrentRow#.val(parseFloat($(this).val()) - #getLast.LCSN#);});">
<cfset TextJS = TextJS & "var $EH_REFH#CurrentRow# = $('##EH_REFH#CurrentRow#');var $MH_REFH#CurrentRow# = $('##MH_REFH#CurrentRow#');$EH_REFH#CurrentRow#.keyup(function () {$MH_REFH#CurrentRow#.val(parseFloat($(this).val()) - #getLast.RTSN#);});">
<cfset TextJS = TextJS & "var $EH_RCYCLES#CurrentRow# = $('##EH_RCYCLES#CurrentRow#');var $MH_RCYCLES#CurrentRow# = $('##MH_RCYCLES#CurrentRow#');$EH_RCYCLES#CurrentRow#.keyup(function () {$MH_RCYCLES#CurrentRow#.val(parseFloat($(this).val()) - #getLast.RCSN#);});">
<cfset TextJS = TextJS & "$MH_LEFH#CurrentRow#.keyup(function () {$EH_LEFH#CurrentRow#.val(parseFloat($(this).val()) + #getLast.LTSN#);});">
<cfset TextJS = TextJS & "$MH_LCYCLES#CurrentRow#.keyup(function () {$EH_LCYCLES#CurrentRow#.val(parseFloat($(this).val()) + #getLast.LCSN#);});">
<cfset TextJS = TextJS & "$MH_REFH#CurrentRow#.keyup(function () {$EH_REFH#CurrentRow#.val(parseFloat($(this).val()) + #getLast.RTSN#);});">
<cfset TextJS = TextJS & "$MH_RCYCLES#CurrentRow#.keyup(function () {$EH_RCYCLES#CurrentRow#.val(parseFloat($(this).val()) + #getLast.RCSN#);});">
```

Comment: I sometimes wonder how some people can work with code like that. It's just unreadable...

Comment: What works great? Do want to round it in JS of CF? Is there a question? I'm so confused.

Comment: @elclanrs some people love cold fusion, I hope I never have to read or write a line of it

Comment: The adding and subtracting works.. when it starts adding and subtracting decimals it views it as 12.1230099999999 I need it to print on the second decimal. Note: This isn't my code. Just what I have to work with.

Comment: Juan, normal ColdFusion code doesn't look like this. Cory: see [cfsavecontent](http://cfdocs.org/cfsavecontent) for an easy improvement.

Comment: You got that right Peter. I've been struggling with this guys code since I saw this project.

Comment: I think it'd get much funnier if it had some JS regular expressions built from CF variables in it :)

Comment: Seriously though.  Stop downvoting the question for crappy code readability. It's the part of the problem posted here.

Comment: haha They can down vote all they want. Real developers know that sometime they have to work with other peoples code that is just horrid. Which is the reason why some people need help in the first place. Every person who downvotes this is just another person who has truely no actual work expierence in the programming business. Thanks for all your help naugtur

Comment: +1 for having to deal with legacy code like this

Comment: *I* downvoted you because your question "didn't show any research effort and it is unclear or not useful". IE: the reason one is *supposed* to down vote questions.  The code is a mess (which, as you say, is neither here nor there), but so was the way you asked your question. My reaction to it was the same as Alex Wayne's. Sorry.

Comment: I did try some code. I tried the Math.round() method. I didn't realize I had to also post my trials and errors as well. I know for future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use `.toFixed`

Detailed documentation is here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

[edit]
My new guess:

```
<cfset TextJS = TextJS & "$MH_LCYCLES#CurrentRow#.keyup(function () {$EH_LCYCLES#CurrentRow#.val((parseFloat($(this).val()) + #getLast.LCSN#).toFixed(2));});">
```

Comment: This adds the number to the field like such.. I added 200.24 in one field but instead of doing the calculation it adds it like this to the second field 200.2423445.454646. As you can see it just added the numbers in front of the calculation

Comment: Ok, then I didn't understand your string-wrapped-oneliner :) You need to call `.toFixed(2)` on the final result of calculation. Otherwise your + operators start concatenating strings.

Comment: I think that did it. Let me rewrite my entire code with it and test! Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I recommend MDN for docs on javascript. If you google any JS code write MDN instead of javascript in your google query. I also altered the first sentence of your question so that people stop downvoting it ;)